# Can I edit the Django administration screen to display my html?

Tags: html, django, admin

Is there a way to display html data on a specific page in the django administrator feature?

For example, let's say I have a programming-language Model, and for each language in the django administrator page, beneath the editing fields section, it display a picture with an html paragraph. A 'Python' language will show a snake picture and some description about it.

Thanks, Alon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override admin `change_form.html` for your model with

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}

{% block after_related_objects %}
    {# put your html here #}
{% endblock %}
```

(Django 1.8 note) Make sure you have specified 'DIRS' key in TEMPLATES dict (settings.py)

```
'DIRS': [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
    ],
```

> templates/
>
> ----admin/
>
> --------app_name/
>
> ------------modelname/
>
> ----------------change_form.html

Comment: Ok! I'll give it a try and let you know