# How to make database fields visible for custom users in Django?

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have a database (mysql, in my case) in which I am trying to store some values using the Models.py. In the admin view page I need to display the fields I have and am doing it using ‍`list_display` in my `ModelAdmin` class. but my requirement is like this.

One of my fields is ‍`owner_name‍` and I just want to display the list only `if owner_name == request.user.email` (user email , other than superuser). So who ever logs in to the admin page other than superuser should should only see all the entries of the model (database fields) whose `request.user.email == owner_name`.

(2) In the search field can search any field  and should edit the fields only when `request.user.email == owner_name`.

Comment: simple solution is override admin `change_form.html` template (idea is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/31136678/3033586 ) and do what you want there

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `ModelAdmin.get_list_display()`. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_list_display You can override it with your business logic.