# django - how to add a link to the admin form view

Tags: django, admin

What I want to do is to make a link in the form view (not in the list view) as shown in the image so that when the current url is http://localhost:8000/admin/myapp/map/3/
the link will be to http://localhost:8000/reports/3.pdf
and note that I do not want to store the pdf in the database.
[image]

I was able to do this using a widget in django-suit.
Here is my code - it might help others:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from suit.widgets import EnclosedInput

class MapForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'info': EnclosedInput(append='<input type="button" class="btn" onclick="window.open(window.location.href.substring(0,window.location.href.indexOf(\'/admin\')) + \'/reports/\' + window.location.href.split(\'/\')[6] + \'.pdf\' );" value="view pdf"/>View pdf'),
        }

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('fname', 'lname', 'age')


@admin.register(Map)
class MapAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('person', 'info')
    form = MapForm
```

Is there a better way of doing this?
I tried using django's fieldsets but I just could not figure out how to do it in a better way.

Note that the link is not really related to the info field but I do not know how to make a separate link or button. Maybe django-suit's HTML5Input widget can be more suitable but the documentation is so cryptic and I do not know what that does.

Update: I also realized that if you append the link button to a select list, django-suit will convert the list to a text input which screws things up.

---

Update:
the following javascript works. It changes the page after dom is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var url = window.location.href.substring(0, window.location.href.indexOf("/admin")) + "/reports/" + window.location.href.split("/")[6] + ".pdf";

   $("#content-main").append('<a href=' + url + '>View Report</a>');
});
```

Comment: You can add it using js https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-asset-definitions

Comment: That's promising. Now I do not need to stick that long javascript within my python code.

Comment: I tried that approach. I cannot execute a javascript to add a link to the content or the main-content because the javascript gets executed prior to the form being loaded. I tried adding my javascript method to the body's onload event but for some weird reason it does not work change the body tag. I do not think there is a way to order the order of javascripts getting loaded.

Comment: ... have you put it in domready?

Comment: Thanks. I tried using the "ready" jquery method and it worked.

Comment: :D anyway you can set order in which your js executed ... idea is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/31136678/3033586 you should override `admin_change_form_document_ready` block

Comment: Interesting. I thought overriding the template is too messy, but overriding change_form.html is not too bad. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Just to share the whole solution:

```
@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('fname', 'lname', 'age')


@admin.register(Map)
class MapAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('person', 'info')
    class Media:
        js = ('report_loader.js',)

// report_loader.js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var url = window.location.href.substring(0, window.location.href.indexOf("/admin")) + "/reports/" + window.location.href.split("/")[6] + ".pdf";

   $("#content-main").append('<a href=' + url + '>View Report</a>');
});
```