# Django (grappelli): how add my own css to all the pages or how to extend admin's base.html?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-grappelli

In Django grappelli, how can I add my own css files to all the admin pages? Or is there a way to extend admin's `base.html` template?

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31135581/can-i-edit-the-django-administration-screen-to-display-my-html

Comment: @AlonWeissfeld not exactly what is need, but thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the complex solution. First of all, I found a [python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-templateloaderwithpriorities/1.0dev) which can help you to tell the Django Template Loader that your template has a highest priority  in comparison with others.

1. `pip install django-templateloaderwithpriorities`
2. In your django settings file put next code:

   TEMPLATE_LOADERS = ('templateloaderwithpriorities.Loader', ) + TEMPLATE_LOADERS
   TEMPLATE_LOADER_PRIORITIES = ['project/admin/templates']
3. In `project/static/css/admin/extra_admin.css` put your css.
4. In `project/admin/templates/admin/base_site.html` (not in `base.html`!) put the next code:

   `{% extends 'admin/base.html' %}
   {% load staticfiles %}
   {% block javascripts %}
       {{ block.super }}
       <script>alert('OK')</script>
   {% endblock %}
   {% block stylesheets %}
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/admin/extra_admin.css' %}">
       {{ block.super }}
   {% endblock %}`
5. That's all! When you go to your site admin page, you see the javascript alert "OK", so in my example I've also included a custom js.

Everything also works fine with Django Grappelli.

Answer (score 2):

- If you want to change the appearance of the admin in general you should override admin templates. This is covered in details here: Overriding admin templates. Sometimes you can just extend the original admin file and then overwrite a block like {% block extrastyle %}{% endblock %} in django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html as an example.
- If your style is model specific you can add additional styles via the Media meta class in your admin.py. See an example here:

`class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        class Media:
            js = ('js/admin/my_own_admin.js',)

            css = {
                 'all': ('css/admin/my_own_admin.css',)
            }`

Comment: I created a template project/admin/templates/admin/base.html and added next: `{% extends 'admin/base.html' %}
{% block extrastyle %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'admin/css/extra_admin.css' %}">
{% endblock %}
`      but there are no changes in admin after my actions.

Comment: This was what I needed. Thanks for showing the way for model specific additional css.

Answer (score 1):

I've stumbled upon the same problem a while ago, but I can't remember where I have found this solution.

If you don't want to include additional dependencies in your project, you can use a little hack: Obviously, you can't just override the `admin/base.html` template and tell it to extend `admin/base.html`, because that would reference to itself.

You can, however, add another template directory that would point to grappelli module location (instead of the `templates` location). The settings would look something like this:

```python
import os

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'DIRS': [
            'your/normal/templates/path',
            os.path.dirname(grappelli.__file__)
        ]
    },
]
```

This way you can  create a `admin/base.html` template, which will extend `templates/admin/base.html` - the latter being the grappelli base template for the admin interface.

Comment: Beautiful solution, but 'DIRS' param released only since Django 1.8

Comment: It will work with TEMPLATE_DIRS in pre-1.8 django versions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#template-dirs - the whole TEMPLATES settings I pasted is just to give context of where the setting should be put.

Comment: Thanks, next time I will try your solution

Answer (score 0):

The admin 'base.html' template can be extended by making an admin directory inside the main app folder. Inside the admin directory create a new file named base.html. Copy these lines in new files.

```
{% extends 'admin/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ block.super }}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'app/js/action.js' %}"></script>

{% endblock %}
{% block stylesheets %}

    {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

Here, I have overridden my javascript using an new script.